# How can I call a Parent function from a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, components, prop

I want my React functional component to call a function in its parent.

I was able to do this with class components like so:

```
<MyChild func={this.functionname} />
```

But I'm having trouble access `this.functionName` withtin my child component, which is a *functional* component.

How can I access this in the child functional component, *as well as within all of its functions (e.g. `useCallback` and `useEffect`)

Comment: Can't you just pass the function into the child component via a prop and then call it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly but you can call a function from the parent component inside the child easily like so:

```js
export function Child({ func }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Calling func');
    func();
  }, [func]);

  return <div>I am the child component</div>;
}

export function Parent() {
  const childFunc = () => console.log('call me!');

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>

      <Child func={childFunc} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To be specific, I'm trying to update a state variable in the parent function *twice* from the child. Once at the beginning of the child function, and once at the end. The state is only changing once, though. Any idea why?

Comment: You're running a state function twice in the same function and expect the state to change mid-function? React can't divide your function and run only half of it so a function will run whole so if you make state changes inside the same function you will have to keep track of that yourself which should be straight forward

Answer (score -2):

The method is accessed in your child component with `this.props.func`.

Comment: Not if the child component is a functional component

Comment: Yep missed that part.